# При обновлении композера выдаёт ошибку "Could not open input file: /var/www/u*******/composer.phar"

Tags: composer

не могу обновить композер с помощью команды **composer update**. Выдаёт ошибку:

```
u*******@u*******.cp.regruhosting.ru [~/public_html/example.com]# composer update
Could not open input file: /var/www/u*******/composer.phar
```

В чём может быть проблема?